# .innerHTML vs .value ... when and why?

Tags: html

When – and why – should one be used over the other.

Sometimes:

element.value = "Fred";                works
and sometimes
element.innerHTML = "Fred";
                                                 works

how come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value` refers to an attribute of a tag, while `innerHTML` refers to the contents between a tag's beginning and end.

**div.innerHTML == "some text"**

```
<div>some text</div>
```

**input.value == "some text"**

```
<input value="some text"/>
```

`innerHTML` also returns child nodes and their content of a parent node, such as:

```
<div id="d"><p>some text</p></div>

var d = document.getElementById("d");
console.log(d.innerHTML); //prints <p>some text</p>
```

Comment: (I'm playing with innerHTML as versus outerHTML. Very interesting!)